# Cursor on build error and temp build directory with TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

### Cursor position on build error

I am using TexStudio with Beamer and TikZ graphic. In general it does a good job to sync TeX and PDF. Anyway, when there is a build error, it tries to move the cursor to the point, but it only seems to go to the end of the guilty slide.

For a general lecture build, going here seems enough. 
BTW, say I am playing with a complex TikZ figure, I do many intermediate builds just to check if I am mistyping something. If this happens, the fact that the cursor slides away every time there is an error results in a loss of productivity.

So I'd like the cursor to remain where it is in case of build errors. How can I do this?

### Temporary build directory

As many others, to reduce the clutter I set this temporary directory.

I set the PdfLaTex command as:

```
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory temp-dir %.tex
```

and, checking `Additional search path` in the build dialog, I set both `Log File` and `PDF Viewer` to `temp-dir`.

Everything is apparently fine, but by chance I noticed that, if, in the root of the TeX file I am going to compile, there is a PDF file with the same basename, then the internal viewer uses this one, despite temp-dir\%.pdf is properly built.

This is not a great annoyance, but I wonder if I set up properly the temporary build directory. Could it be that TeXStudio searches in the TeX root directory first and on a "second thought" in the temp-dir?  If this were the case, I suspect that this could slow down the compilation.

There is not much documentation concerning temporary build directories, so I am seeking for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. The cursor currently always moves to the error location. But we may add an option to switch this off in the future.
2. It's true, that the file directory is always searched before the `Additional search path`. That's why it's *additional*. This does not have an influence on compilation speed.